# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine - Tomcat server on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, jvm, fatal-error

I installed Tomcat 7.0.82 on Mac OS platform and tried to run a web application. However, I got:

```
/Users/nazar/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/bin/catalina.sh run
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/nlelyak/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Disconnected from server
```

I created `setenv.sh` at bin folder with content:

> CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"

It didn't solve the issue.

Java version is following:

```
➜  bin java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an increased version of Tomcat `apache-tomcat-8.5.24`.

And now everything is working fine.

Still, have no idea why for 7 it fails.

Comment: maybe no more `endorsed` directory in tomcat 8.5?